# Android Dev Relative and Linear Layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

When I have buttons on the xml page, moving or enlarging them is very frustrating because i can't make them go where I want. Sometimes if I want to move something to the right it'll instead move somewhere else randomly or nothing will happen. Is this because of the relativelayout? And what's the difference between relative and linear layouts?

Answer (score 0):

1) RelativeLayout - Views inside a RelativeLayout are relative to the position of other children in the RelativeLayout.

2) LinearLayout - Views inside the LinearLayout are in a linear pattern either horizontal or vertical.

I personally rarely use RelativeLayout unless it is inside a LinearLayout and I need to position a single view in an odd place against the horizontal or vertical aspect of LinearLayout. RelativeLayout can be confusing because if you change the dimensions of one view in it you have to adjust the dimensions of all other views that are relative to that view.

Comment: when i tried using linear layout, i couldn't move it wherever, it was like 6 different spots in a grid format